# Python subprocess. read what was written to a file by other process

Tags: python, subprocess

I have two python programs. One of them writes something to a file and another must check if written line is the needed data, i must check only the last written line. I must use subprocess to complete this task. Any ideas ?
This is what I have now: 
Function that writes something to a file:

```
def write_num_time(NUM_TIMES, FILENAME):
    while NUM_TIMES > 0:
        with open(FILENAME, 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(randint(1,10)) + ' ' + time.strftime("%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S\n"))
        time.sleep(1)
        print(NUM_TIMES)
        NUM_TIMES = NUM_TIMES - 1
```

Comment: Why must you use subprocess?  Just open the file in the other process.  You should try stating your question in terms of what you're trying to accomplish, not necessarily what you think you need to do to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just redirect the output from `process1` to `process2` input.

Example:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE

proc1 = subprocess.Popen(some_programm, stdout=PIPE, ...) # The others arguments where omitted for brevity.
proc2 = subprocess.Popen(some_other_program, stdin=proc1.stdout, ...) # The others arguments where omitted for brevity.
```

Then in `proc2` implementation you can read line by line from input. Implementing of processes is up to you.

If also you need log the dates (I just realized your function works with dates :D) you can delegate that task to the process who receives the data (in this example `proc2`).